# dynamically select arbitrary n columns with window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

Abstract of my real select statement:

```
select 
  lag(somecol) over (partition by thing_id) as prev_1,
  lag(somecol,2) over (partition by thing_id) as prev_2,
  lag(somecol,3) over (partition by thing_id) as prev_3,
  othercol,
  ...
```

In the real query the `over` is much more complex which leads to pretty dense, unreadable code.  Additionally, getting the last 3 rows is hardcoded (vs n=whatever).

Is there any way in straight SQL to iteratively or recursively specify these `prev_x` columns, so that 1) the code is more readable and 2) you could dynamically specify the number n of prev cols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer just the first question, to make the code more readable, Postgres allows to define the window, name it and then reference it several times in the query.

See the docs for [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

> When a query involves multiple window functions, it is possible to
>   write out each one with a separate OVER clause, but this is
>   duplicative and error-prone if the same windowing behavior is wanted
>   for several functions. Instead, each windowing behavior can be named
>   in a WINDOW clause and then referenced in OVER. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT sum(salary) OVER w, avg(salary) OVER w
> FROM empsalary
> WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC);
> ```

I don't know if this feature is part of the SQL standard or not, but I know that SQL Server doesn't support it.

So, your query would look like this:

```
select 
  lag(somecol) over w as prev_1,
  lag(somecol,2) over w as prev_2,
  lag(somecol,3) over w as prev_3,
  othercol,
  ...
from
  ...
WINDOW w AS (partition by thing_id)
;
```

---

Regarding your second question how to "dynamically specify the number n of prev cols" - you'll need to generate the text of `SELECT` statement dynamically to achieve that. RDBMS assume stable schema, i.e. the number of columns in tables and queries is usually fixed, not dynamic.

Comment: This addresses the readability issue, much better now.  I can't dynamically generate the SELECT so I'll live with "hard-coding" the column count.